# Why is Vagrant hosting my project directory on the guest machine?

Tags: vagrant

For a project with a file `/foo/bar/Vagrantfile`, Vagrant shares/syncs `/foo/bar` on the host machine as `/vagrant` on the guest machine.

Why is it doing this? It appears to be undesirable: the whole point is achieving isolation, but this sharing destroys isolation: a buggy VM can delete my project directory, and my tinkering with my project can affect the VM.

So, what is the point of this? Is it necessary for something I've overlooked?

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant by default sync the project directory (where `Vagrantfile` resides) with `/vagrant` within the guest.

If it is **NOT** desired, it can be disabled by explicitly disable the synced folder config in `Vagrantfile` and then a `vagrant reload` is needed.

`config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true`

If one-off or manual sync is required, use the new `rsync` type added in vagrant 1.5.x.